# Setting up Fedora alongside Windows 8 with special considerations

Tags: linux, windows-8, ntfs, ext4

I've recently found myself much more comfortable using the console and other tools on my Mac than their counterparts with Windows.  Specifically, these tools include LaTeX/`xindy`, `emacs` and its load files, dev, and various other things.  I have decided to go ahead and install Fedora 17 on my desktop and I wish to be able to boot from either Windows or Fedora relatively seamlessly (and I recognize that this will *likely* mean a boot menu).  I created a bootable USB (my tower lacks an optical bay at the moment, for financial reasons) and was all ready to install Fedora. I went into Disk Management to create a partition for Fedora when I noticed one crucial little piece of awful: both my boot drive and my data drive are formatted as `NTFS`.

Now, this would not be a problem if I were just creating a new partition for major separation in data for use with Windows.  However, I need to be able to easily access (read/write) all of my data from both the Windows environment and with Fedora.  (I know about third-party explorers, but I'd much prefer to stick with the defaults.)

It is my understanding that Windows is to `NTFS` as Fedora/Linux is to `ext4`.  This raises the present questions:

- Does Fedora have any problem with using a different file-system from `ext4`, such as `exFAT`?
- It is my understanding that Windows cannot read/write `ext4` through the Explorer.  Has this fact changed through any recent plugins?
- Will this affect Windows' or Fedora's ability to hibernate?  (My guess is no, but it's a concern.)
- A major use of my desktop is the use of Adobe software, specifically Premiere and After Effects.  I'm assuming Adobe will be able to read whatever the Explorer can read, but I was wondering if there are any special concerns to note.

More as they come back to mind - but these are the important ones.

Comment: As an aside, I'd ask if there is a better way to reformat a disk.  Right now, I'm going with a shrink-format-copy approach until all the data is moved to the new partition, and then rejoin them.  I don't think there are any concerns with this, but I certainly stand to be corrected.

Comment: Fedora should be able to access NTFS using ntfs-3g. As for Windows, [there are apps and even an FS driver](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) to access Ext2/3/4 partitions.